# Google analytic keywords show some results like %d8%b3%d9%86%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1

Tags: google-analytics

In google analytic when i check keyword searched by google search engine ,i see that some results are non-readable like  :

%d8%b3%d9%86%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1

and my site is in Persian ,how can i solve this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It's URL-encoded.  In JavaScript, you can use [`decodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

decodeURIComponent("%d8%b3%d9%86%d8%aa%d9%88%d8%b1") gives "سنتور", which is still unreadable to me. ;)

On the server-side, your language should have an equivalent for URL-decoding.

Comment: Thanks, but it is ok and readable in persian (it is name on an instrument in persian music),please explain more about using "decodeURIComponent" .

Comment: @Kaveh, that was a joke.  Apparently, it means [dulcimer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Dulcimer).  decodeURIComponent is a function that takes encoded URL parts and decodes them.  I'll add a link to the documentation.

Comment: My server-side language is php,but it is not clear for me that searching a keyword in google has what relation to my site ?

Comment: @Kaveh, I don't understand your question.  However, in PHP you can use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Comment: Matthew, the point is the data he's seeing in his Google Analytics data is encoded in this way. It's not a result of anything he's doing -- it's something with Google Analytics itself.

Comment: @yahelc, I didn't say he was encoding it.  I explained how to decode it, which I think addresses his issue.

Comment: Yes,when i open google analytic for checking the searched keywords ,then i see that some keywords are coded like my example in question.

Comment: @Matthew Flaschen,sorry for my delay,i think that it doesn't regard to my site ,i open google analytic and see the keywords that users have searched some keywords are coded and others are ok,i have found that if people search my site in address bar instead of search box this happen.

Comment: @Kaveh, I don't know how to prevent them being encoded.  That would require more investigation.